# sub document under main document how to get a listing with pagination using couchbase(N1QL) query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

any one can help me how to get the sub document List with pagination

i just give a sample example :

```
{
  "accessories": [`

    {
      "data": {
        "name": "TEST",
       "updated_at": "2020-03-27T16:16:20.818Z"
      },
      "id": "56e83ea1-042e-47e0-85f8-186189c37426"
    }

  ],

  "calibration_reports": [`

    {

      "data": {
        "deleted_at": "",
        "frm27_equipment": [
          "test_cat1"
        ],
        "frm27_link": [
          "yes"
        ],
        "frm27_submit": null,
        "updated_at": "2020-03-30T10:24:52.703Z"
      },
      "id": "e4c8b1b4-7f37-46db-a49d-bca74482b968"
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "deleted_at": "",
        "frm27_equipment": [
          "test_cat1"
        ],
        "frm27_link": [
          "no"
        ],
        "frm27_submit": null,
        "updated_at": "2020-03-30T10:34:37.615Z"
      },
      "id": "445854d6-66bf-4e33-b620-05a5053119a8"
    }

  ],

    }

  ]

}
```

Here i want to get a **calibration_reports** list with pagination is it possible ? using couchbase (N1ql Query)
please if any one know, what is the process how to get the list of result with pagination using couchbase(N1QL) query. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to go about this is to use `UNNEST`.

For instance:

```
SELECT calreports.id
FROM utpal u
UNNEST u.calibration_reports calreports
```

This would return something like:

```
[
  { "id": "aaa" },
  { "id": "bbb" },
  { "id": "ccc" }, 
   ... etc ...
]
```

And then you can use normal `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` for pagination, like so:

```
SELECT calreports.id
FROM utpal u
UNNEST u.calibration_reports calreports
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 150;
```